# Mysql comparing time in terms of seconds

Tags: mysql

i have a question such as i am suppose to write an sql query to find out the people who had better timings in at least 4 stages(a total of 21 stage) than this particular person. The timings are stored in seconds. i.e i have to compare a group of people timings with ths particular person timings and if they are faster in at least 4 stages then their names will be displayed.

Comment: how did you define column type?

Comment: Stages (stage_id, took_place, start_loc, end_loc, distance, description)

Comment: Riders (rider_id, name) Results (stage_id, rider_id, time_seconds)

Comment: these are my 3 relations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact schema so I could only base on what you described. Here is a very basic example with schema and query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/717356/5

The query itself should look something like this:

```
select t.user_id, count(*) as better_stages from timings t
join timings base on (base.stage = t.stage and not t.user_id = base.user_id)
where base.user_id = 1 and base.timing > t.timing
group by user_id
having better_stages >= 4;
```

This you should be able to change to work with your schema. Join to the user table or whatever else needs to be tuned.

Comment: Stages (stage_id, took_place, start_loc, end_loc, distance, description) Riders (rider_id, name) Results (stage_id, rider_id, time_seconds) these are my 3 relations how do i go about using your statement for my relations?

Comment: It's very simple, you just join Riders if you want to show the name of the rider. You don'T need the stages tables:

select Riders.name, t.rider_id, count(*) as better_stages from Results t
join Results base on (base.stage_id = t.stage_id and not t.user_id = base.user_id)
join Riders on (t.rider_id = Riders.id)
where base.rider_id = 1 and base.timing > t.timing
group by rider_id
having better_stages >= 4;